# "cl-labels with dynamic scoping is not implemented"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to use cl-labels in an Emacs package I'm writing. A user has filed a bug report with a problem that I'm not observing in my own Emacs at version 24.3.1, but this user is on 24.3.2.

https://github.com/d11wtq/fiplr/issues/3

```
`cl-labels' with dynamic scoping is not implemented
```

I'm using `cl-labels` here: https://github.com/d11wtq/fiplr/blob/f368e84410d2ee57117b2d6501c0cf42359bc252/fiplr.el#L154-L177

```
;; Builds a gigantic `find' shell command with -prune, -o, -not and shit.
(defun fiplr-list-files-shell-command (type path ignored-globs)
  "Builds the `find' command to locate all project files & directories."
  "Path is the base directory to recurse from."
  "Ignored-globs is an alist with keys 'directories and 'files."
  (cl-labels ((type-abbrev (assoc-type)
                (cl-case assoc-type
                  ('directories "d")
                  ('files "f")))
              (name-matcher (glob)
                (mapconcat 'identity
                           `("-name" ,(shell-quote-argument glob))
                           " "))
              (grouped-name-matchers (type)
                (mapconcat 'identity
                           `(,(shell-quote-argument "(")
                             ,(mapconcat #'name-matcher
                                      (cadr (assoc type ignored-globs))
                                      " -o ")
                             ,(shell-quote-argument ")"))
                           " "))
              (matcher (assoc-type)
                (mapconcat 'identity
                           `(,(shell-quote-argument "(")
                             "-type"
                             ,(type-abbrev assoc-type)
                             ,(grouped-name-matchers assoc-type)
                             ,(shell-quote-argument ")"))
                           " ")))
    (mapconcat 'identity
               `("find"
                 ,(shell-quote-argument (directory-file-name path))
                 ,(matcher 'directories)
                 "-prune"
                 "-o"
                 "-not"
                 ,(matcher 'files)
                 "-type"
                 ,(type-abbrev type)
                 "-print")
               " ")))
```

Now, the only reason I'm using `cl-labels` is to allow some private internal functions to be used, and each of those functions depends on others one declared in the `cl-labels` definition.

I don't need dynamic scoping neither. Is there a macro the gives me what I want, or should I just switch to longer named global functions? (which does kind of suck given how irrelevant these functions are to other parts of the code)

Basically I need something like `letrec` from Scheme, or `labels` from Common Lisp.

EDIT | I ended up just using a liberal combination of `(lambda () .. )`, `(funcall ...)` and `(let* ...)`. Would love to know if there's a more elegant solution that actually works in Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks perfectly fine.  And there's no error like the one you cite in Emacs's own source code, so the error is signaled by some external package.  Finally There's no "24.3.1" or "24.3.2" release.  There's only a "24.3" release, and the additional ".1" or ".2" is just a build number, so your bug-reporter is using the same version of Emacs as you.  He probably happens to be using a package that has a bug.

Comment: I think the reporter must be using a version from source control, not an official release. However, from that code, it looks like I could just turn on lexical scoping for that file? I've never done that, but I assume that is just: `(setq file-local-variables-alist '((lexical-scoping . t)))`

Comment: Aha!  Thanks wvxvw for showing that I'm the culprit.  Indeed, I had forgotten about that message.  So it comes from the cl-lib compatibility library.  So indeed, if you add a `-*- lexical-binding: t -*-` cookie at the top of your file, your code should work (because when using lexical scoping, `cl-labels` is the same as cl.el's `labels`, so `cl-lib` can just use cl's `labels`, whereas under the default dynamic binding, the behavior of `cl-labels` and that of `labels` is supposed to be slightly different, so `cl-lib` would have to reimplement it, which it doesn't bother to do).

Comment: Does adding that comment at the top of my file potentially break other packages? I tried to read up on the settings for lexical-binding and the manual talks of file-local variables, set via some alist, but doesn't mention these magic comments, unless I missed it. I saw somebody's README say to add that comment, but warned of it breaking other things.

Comment: That setting does affect the code in the rest of your file and may hence break some of your code but it does not affect other packages.  These magic comments *are* file-local variables.  `file-local-variables-alist` is a variable used internally in the implementation of those magic comments.

Comment: I released a new version of the cl-lib compatibility package, where the message more clearly refers to `lexical-binding` and where the error is turned into a simple message.